# changing width/height pixels without caring for aspect ratio

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Putting in different ways:
1) How to change the width of image without changing it's height in **python**. 
2) Let aspect ratio get changed, How can I change just one of height or width.(All   in terms of pixels.)
3) Image is of pixels a*b, I want to change it to an image of pixels c*d. And there is not aspect ration relation between these numbers. They are all random numbers.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What do you mean *change*?  Do you want to stretch and shrink the image to the right size or crop it and add black?

Comment: I want to stretch or shrink the image. Don't want to crop the image.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the Pillow library:

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open("/path/to/my/file")
image.resize((c, d)) # You can make quality of higher priority than speed by adding Image.ANTIALIAS as a second argument.
image.save("/path/to/my/changed/file")
```